# insert global variable to textbox html

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to put a global variable into a textbox so when I run the code it will automatically assign the value based on the variable using this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var m = 1;
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function autofill(){
    var object = document.getElementsById('id_textbox');
    object.item(0).value=m;
}
</script>
```

html

```
</head>
<body onload="autofill();">
<input type="text" name="name_textbox" id="id_textbox" />

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when i try to open it my web browser, the textbox doesnt have any value. what would be the problem?

Comment: you've mispelled `getElementsById`, it should be `getElementById`

Comment: Also, you seem to have an extra `<script>` tag between the global var and the function.

Comment: omg yea my fault it was originally getElementsByName but i change it to getElementsById.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function should read

```
function autofill(){
 var object = document.getElementById('id_textbox');
    object.value=m;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uFxBr/)

because `getElementsById` is not a function (remember, element id must be unique so getElements would not make sense - perhaps you confused it with [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp))

Also, I'd recommend always using the F12 browser debug tools when trying these things out - you will be able to get instant feedback on typos, syntax errors, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need close script tag after var `m = 1;` and change getElementsById to getElementById

Comment: you also need to change `object.item(0).value` to `object.value`.

Comment: I missed something? There is no `getElementsById` method of document.